cd command does not work from .readthedocs.yaml
This my yaml file, https://gitlab.com/miroi/dirac-fork/-/blob/rtd_documentation/.readthedocs.yaml?ref_type=heads
and this is the output from documentation buildup : https://readthedocs.org/projects/dirac-fork/builds/26198759/ .
The cd command of https://gitlab.com/miroi/dirac-fork/-/blob/rtd_documentation/.readthedocs.yaml?ref_type=heads#L41 is not working ... It gives 0 return code, but there is no moving into the wanted subdirectory.
Why ? Is it intentional ?

We need enough content to understand the problem included in the text of the question itself. Links are fine for supplemental purposes but the question needs to make sense even if they all break; the best way to correct this is probably to [edit] a transcript of what you did, and its unexpected outcome, into the question itself.

We do not accept links to off-site locations for information needed for your question. All relevant information has to be here, in the question itself, so that it remains available for future users. For more information, see the [help/on-topic] and [mre].

That said, note that cd only impacts the shell it's run in, not any parent process; so it's 100% normal that any process that runs sh -c 'cd somedir' or equivalents won't have its (that is to say, the parent process's) working directory changed.

I guess that each command creates its own shell, just like make does.
Try merging it into a single, ugly, line
cd $READTHEDOCS_OUTPUT/; pwd; ls -lt; cmake ..; make html; exit 0


If this is the OP's problem, we have lots of duplicates that already cover the issue, so the question should be closed rather than answered. (And one should really always have a || exit after a cd so the subsequent commands can't be run in the wrong directory -- also, exit 0 is a bad idea; it'll mask errors, whereas if you leave it off you get the default behavior of exit $? that passes through the exit status from the prior command, in this case that of make)

Thanks ! The advice "all in one line" helped. Question is answered.
